# imagecreatefromjpeg() HTTP request failure

Tags: php, parameters, httprequest, imagecreatefrompng

i am using this function to copy an image from a given url.

i am getting this error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(http://preview.netcarshow.com/Ford-Focus_RS500-2011-hd.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden in /var/www/clients/client2/web3/web/process/updatebuildinfo.php on line 68 Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/clients/client2/web3/web/process/updatebuildinfo.php on line 69 Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/clients/client2/web3/web/process/updatebuildinfo.php on line 70 AdminCraig,376http://preview.netcarshow.com/Ford-Focus_RS500-2011-hd.jpg
```

The code im using is this:

```
$imagefile = $_POST['updatebuildcover'];
$resource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagefile);
imagejpeg($resource, "images/covers/$imagepath.jpeg", 25);
imagedestroy($resource);
echo $imagepath;
echo $imagefile;
```

The image path is a string thats created earlier on, and as you can see when i echo both of the $imagefile and the path they are working fine.

I have used this exact code before and worked fine.

Any ideas on whats causing this?

Comment: See the manual for a potential problem: `A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.`

Comment: They must be as i use this same code on another process script on my website :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the destination website (preview.netcarshow.com) is rejecting your GET request, as you can see the HTTP 403 status code:

**HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden**

This is an HTTP error thrown by the web server.

Maybe the mentioned web server reject the download from automated scripts?

Comment: seems to be the case. Used a different URL and it worked fine. Didnt know that it was possible or someone to block the request.